# Render Flutter Widget on Canvas - CustomPainter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart, widget

I was looking into building a game with Flutter. I have made multiple apps with Flutter already, but haven't really used the CustomPainter widgets a lot. I can make a lot of the UI I want to with Widgets rather than creating my own custom shape. So how do I convert a widget to an object that I can render on the canvas?